# Magento Shipping method table rate: weight vs destination

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Using table rate with weight vs destination has been the best shipping method available for any kind of shop.

I am trying to use the same for a shop with a country having 4000 post codes. All 4000 post codes are divided into 5 categories each of these 5 categories will have different price rules. The main problem here is after every 1000gm price increases by certain amount.

For e.g., category 1:  if price is $5 for 1000gm for certain postcode,

- if the person buys 2000gm then the price will be $5+$2 = $7 ($2 for each 1000gm)
- if the person buys 3000gm then the price will be $5+$2+$2 = $9

For e.g., category 2:  if price is $8 for 1000gm for certain postcode,

- if the person buys 2000gm then the price will be $8+$4 = $12 ($4 for each 1000gm)
- if the person buys 3000gm then the price will be $8+$4+$4 = $16

```
    Country Region/State    Zip/PostalCode  Weight (and above)  Shipping Price
    KKK        *                1009                0                   5
    KKK        *                1009               1000                 7
    KKK        *                1009               2000                 9
    KKK        *                1010                0                   8
    KKK        *                1010               1000                 12
    KKK        *                1010               2000                 16
```

There are 5 categories and person can buy any amount.

How can I create such type of calculation with table rate?